# DynamicDataDisplay and other charting libraries for WPF apps

Tags: wpf, charts, dynamic-data-display

I am looking for a feature rich charting library, I've seen infragistics but it is not performant enough when there are many data points rendered, on the other hand I see DynamicDataDisplay is a pretty awesome library, but the project is not maintained anymore. Could you list other charting libraries that I should be aware of. I am looking from performance and customizability criteria.

Comment: did you try Telerik?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to download a trial version of [LightningChart](http://arction.com/), the fastest  and fully configurable Charting and Data visualization components for .Net. Examples are included in download package.
You also can read about benchmark and see for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I have plotted line charts with around a million data points using [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com), and it can plot it well within 1 second. However, ChartDirector is a Windows Forms control, so it needs to be hosted in a WindowsFormsHost control when used in WPF. You can also just display the chart as an image in a WPF image control, but then you lose the user interaction features (track cursors, drag to zoom/scroll, ...).